# no constraint when referencing a table

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I've been reading the previous threads about postgresql and this problem, and I've been sitting with it for a while without any progress.
So i have three tables who looks like this:

```
create table Band
( 
  bandID SERIAL primary key,
  BandNamn char(20)
);

create table Bandinformation(
  id SERIAL UNIQUE,
  bandID integer UNIQUE,
  Medlemmar char(40),
  Land char(20),

  primary key(id, bandID),
  foreign key(bandID) references Band(bandID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

create table medlemsinfo(
    id SERIAL,
    koppladTillMedlem integer UNIQUE,
    text char(100),

    primary key(id, koppladTillMedlem),
    foreign key(koppladTillMedlem) references Bandinformation(bandID) ON DELETE CASCADE

);
```

However, when i try to reference "koppladTillMedlem" to bandID in the column  Bandinformation, it will not allow me since there's no unique constraint.
But from what i can read, and what i've done, i've set all the things to unique and they are both primary keys, so i dont see the problem..
What can i do to solve this, i've read about it on postgresql's website but im getting so frustrated about it.

Comment: which Postgres version?

Comment: because even Postres 8.4 allows it. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=96469c9b22e59e8a0dc936e838bd9ca7

Answer (score -1):

Solved it, the problem was that im having a primary key in the table medlemsinfo on koppladTillMedlem, dont understand why though because "primary key" should automatically set it to Unique..